# Set selected row colour in uwp communitytoolkit datagrid

Tags: uwp, colors, datagrid, selection

I am doing my first uwp project and am using the community toolkit datagrid
I have managed to get the styling of the grid more or less like I want it but I must be overlooking how to change the color of the selected row (default seems to be blue, I want it to be a bit lighter)

Anyone, any ideas? 
cheers
Jeroen

Comment: Please, share your code

Answer (score 2):

The DataGrid has a `RowStyle` property that can be used to set the color of the row (including the selected row color).

**Style**

```xml
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MySelectedRowBackground" Color="Blue" Opacity="0.7"/>

<Style x:Key="BasicDataGridRowStyle" TargetType="controls:DataGridRow">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:DataGridRow">
                <localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid x:Name="RowRoot">
                    <localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.RowDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NormalAlternatingRow"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MySelectedRowBackground}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:.2" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NormalSelected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MySelectedRowBackground}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MySelectedRowBackground}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverUnfocusedSelected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MySelectedRowBackground}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="UnfocusedSelected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource MySelectedRowBackground}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Invalid">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="InvalidVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.4"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="Transparent"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="InvalidVisualElement" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledAccentBrush}" Opacity="0"/>
                    <localprimitives:DataGridRowHeader x:Name="RowHeader" localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.IsFrozen="True" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                    <localprimitives:DataGridCellsPresenter x:Name="CellsPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Grid.Column="1" localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.IsFrozen="True" MinHeight="32"/>
                    <localprimitives:DataGridDetailsPresenter x:Name="DetailsPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="BottomGridLine" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
                </localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Use**

```xml
<controls:DataGrid RowStyle="{StaticResource BasicDataGridRowStyle}">
    ...
</controls:DataGrid>
```

You can modify `MySelectedRowBackground` to change to your favorite color, or you can create different colors for reference based on the different states of Row.

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you so much. It looks a bit complicated, however, if it works I am happy

Comment: This style is changed by the default style of the DataGrid. Although it looks a bit long, it has very good customization features, and I look forward to the results you are trying.

Comment: How to change foreground ?